# How to override AddressSanitizer callback functions (e.g. `__asan_on_error`)

Tags: rust, ffi, address-sanitizer, sanitizer

I'm trying to interact with interfaces of AddressSanitizer while using Rust, but I'm having some difficulties.

Specifically, I want to write a hook that is called immediately when ASan detects an error. For this purpose, I have tried to override `__asan_on_error` function as the following:

```rust
use std::hint::black_box;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn __asan_on_error() -> libc::c_void {
    std::process::abort();
}

fn main() {
    let ptr = Box::into_raw(Box::new(1));
    unsafe { drop(Box::from_raw(ptr)) };
    black_box(unsafe { *black_box(ptr) } + 1);
}
```

Run with:

```bash
RUSTFLAGS="-Z sanitizer=address" cargo run --profile=dev --target aarch64-apple-darwin
```

The intended result of the code above would be aborting the program before printing error messages. However, it does not abort the program and prints all logs for the error.

It gives me headache because an equivalant code written in C++ works as intended (abort before printing the logs).

```cpp
#include <sanitizer/asan_interface.h>
#include <cstdlib>

extern "C" void __asan_on_error() {
    abort();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    volatile int* ptr = (int*)std::malloc(sizeof(int));
    std::free((void*)ptr);
    volatile int _ = *ptr + 1;
}
```

Run with:

```bash
clang -o main -x c++ -O -g -fsanitize=address main.cpp && ASAN_OPTIONS=symbolize=1 ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH=$(which llvm-symbolizer) ./main
```

In summary, my question is the following:

**Is it possible to override AddressSanitizer callback functions in Rust? If so, how to do that, and what did I miss?**

---

Additionally, I tried calling other functions in `asan_interface.h`, such as `__asan_describe_address`, to find out whether the Rust compiler is linking my binary to the ASan library or not. For example, I have written an experimental code like the following:

```rust
extern "C" {
    fn __asan_describe_address(addr: *mut libc::c_void) -> libc::c_void;
}

fn main() {
    let ptr = Box::into_raw(Box::new(1));
    unsafe { __asan_describe_address(ptr as _) };
}
```

Run with:

```bash
RUSTFLAGS="-Z sanitizer=address" cargo run --profile=dev --target aarch64-apple-darwin
```

Surprisingly, it actually works, printing out the logs about the given pointer. It proves that it is possible to call ASan function from the Rust, but the callback implementation in Rust is not recognized by the ASan library for some reasons, even though it has both `#[no_mangle]` and `pub extern "C"`.